# Create Array List dynamically from Javascript Object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Alright, so I'd like to create a selector with different US States,
I'll be using [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/usa-states) package, which for the input:

```js
var usStates = new UsaStates();
console.log(usStates.states);`
```

outputs:

```
{
    name: "Alabama",
    abbreviation: "AL",
    territory: false,
    capital: "Montgomery",
    contiguous: true
},
{
    name: "Alaska",
    abbreviation: "AK",
    territory: false,
    capital: "Juneau",
    contiguous: false
},
...(other states omitted for brevity)
{
    name: "Wyoming",
    abbreviation: "WY",
    territory: false,
    capital: "Cheyenne",
    contiguous: true
}
```

I already have a selector component, but it takes options as an array prop like so:

```
<LNSelect
                options={[
                  { label: "Alabama", value: "AL" },
                  { label: "New York", value: "NY" },
                ]}
></LNSelect>
```

How can I use the package's functionality to create an Array in the necessary format with label as the name and value as the abbreviation?

Many thanks!

Comment: You can use [.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides being able to map it yourself just using JS, the documentation specifies you can create a custom format, which for you would be:

```
var myCustomStates = usStates.format({
    $label: 'name',
    $value: 'abbreviation',
});
```

Where the '$' translates to the literal string you want, and otherwise the package attempts to link specific values to the key/value (e.g. 'name' would become "New York", and '$name' would simply become 'name').

(For any package, just read the documentation first.)

Comment: I'll be using this but since it's not the direct answer to the question won't be selecting it as the answer. Thank you for pointing out the function exists, my bad :)

Comment: Whether you use `.map` or this, it matters little, but the question was "how can I use the **package's functionality** to create an Array in the necessary format with label as the name and value as the abbreviation?" ;)

Answer (score 2):

Transforming arrays is usually done with [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). Simply call map on the array of states if it's already provided in that format, or use [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to transform the object to an array for use with map.

```js
const states = [{
    name: "Alabama",
    abbreviation: "AL",
    territory: false,
    capital: "Montgomery",
    contiguous: true
},
{
    name: "Alaska",
    abbreviation: "AK",
    territory: false,
    capital: "Juneau",
    contiguous: false
},
{
    name: "Wyoming",
    abbreviation: "WY",
    territory: false,
    capital: "Cheyenne",
    contiguous: true
}];

const options = states.map(state => {
  return {
    label: state.name,
    value: state.abbreviation
  }
});

console.log(options);
```